# Override Joomla's JomSocial's About Me template?

Tags: templates, joomla, overriding

Specifically, I'd like to override `JOOMLA\components\com_community\templates\jomsocial\layouts\profile\focus.php`

But I can't see how.

The containing page is visible at `http://example.dev/profile/my-profile` and I'll override the whole thing if necessary.

https://www.jomsocial.com/company/docs/template/customizing-template/customizing-jomsocial-template only mentions the files in `JOOMLA\components\com_community\templates\default`

Any advice, even if it's "You can't!" will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do override for:

ROOT/components/com_community/templates/jomsocial/layouts/profile/focus.php

Then just copy focus.php to:

ROOT/templates/your-template/html/com_community/layouts/profile